# Content Search webpart configuration - Help

Tags: content-search-web-part

I have configured the search webpart to show list of documents with icon and it works.
But its showing this

```
icon file name
some description which is some content in the file itself
```

my settings here :- 
[image]

What do I need to do to get rid of this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's how it works, its by design what is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if its by design as I recall I have see the search wepart configured with no description.Im after if there is a property to be set to remove it

Comment: By default search web part will have description, if you want to remove it you will have to create a custom item display template and remove the field rendering description keeping rest as in original template